# flexslider and jquery tools overlay - accessing the slider object

Tags: javascript, jquery, flexslider

I'm using [flexslider](http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/) inside of [jquery tools overlay](http://jquerytools.org/demos/overlay/index.html)

I want to access the slider on show and hide of the overlay.

```
var slideToJumpTo  = 5; //this changes
var modals = ({
init: function(){
    $("div[rel]").overlay({         
        onBeforeLoad: function() {
                    //I want to be able to access the flexslider here.
                    //So I can do something like $('slider').jumpToSlide(slideToJumpTo) - dummy code
        },
        onLoad: function() {        
            $.getScript('/js/libs/jquery.flexslider-min.js', function() {
                if ($('.overlay-carousel').length > 0) {
                    $('.overlay-carousel').flexslider({

                    });
                }
            });             
        },
        onClose:function(){

        }
    });
}
});
```

How should I reference the slider?